# using action script how to draw a one circle with diffrent color's

Tags: actionscript-3

using action script how to draw a circle that have more than 2 or 3 color'si.e if circle is divded in to 3 parts then i will draw that circle with 3 diffrent color's..means that 3 arcs forma complete circle

Comment: i know how to draw a circle ..withn opne color..i am not getting how to dra a circle with diffrent colors

Comment: "diffrent color's" seriously?

Answer (score 0):

there is a tutorial from [pixelwit](http://www.pixelwit.com/blog/2007/07/draw-an-arc-with-actionscript/)
that shows how to draw an arc

Answer (score 0):

Draw your color regions, then apply circle mask to them:

```
    //draw two colored stripes
    var shape:Shape = new Shape();
    var g:Graphics = shape.graphics;
    g.beginFill(0xFF0000);
    g.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 50);
    g.endFill();
    g.beginFill(0xFFFF00);
    g.drawRect(0, 50, 100, 50);
    g.endFill();

    //create circle mask
    var mask:Shape = new Shape();
    g = mask.graphics;
    g.beginFill(0xFFFFFF);
    g.drawCircle(50, 50, 50);
    g.endFill();

    //now shape is two-colored circle
    shape.mask = mask;
```